# Calculating Data rate function of bandwidth and SNR

Tags: modulation, matlab, demodulation, signal-to-noise, bpsk

I plotted BER vs SNR for BPSK modulation in Matlab and I am given bandwidth of channel (bandlimited channel). lets say it is BW1. I would like to find the data rate based on this information. I am using Shannon capacity formula: Therefore

C=BW*log2(1+SNR).

However I wonder for this equation the bandwidth is actually bandwidth of my channel or not? also what is the SNR since in Matlab we usually loop through the eb/No and call that one SNR can I use that value for SNR or should I convert it to real SNR by multiplying by a constant?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your Eb/N0 to S/N . S (Signal power) is (Eb (bit energy) * Rb (bit rate)). N (Noise power) is N0 (noise power per Hz) * B (channel bandwidth).

so, SNR = Eb/N0 x Rb/B